# K8s Pod Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: kubernetes, hook

I'd like to receive a notification whenever there are any changes to the kubernetes cluster. Pods are created/deleted, etc. This can be a in a form of a webhook, or a message in a pub/sub, etc anything that can be used in autonomous manner.

Running the kubernetes cluster in gcp.

Comment: This question does not strictly ask a specific question - and is a bit broad. You can write a controller which is listening to objects that you care about and then send events to a place you want. [PLUG] We are writing a simple bot that can send such events to Slack: https://www.botkube.io/

Comment: could you share some details on how to write such a controller? and how to plug it in to kubernetes?

Comment: you can also check this etcd metrics `sum(rate(etcd_object_counts{resource="pods"}[1m]))`, it will give you a rough overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get such events with creating hooks in linux compatible languages (such as go,python etc.) to relevant k8s object's watch endpoint. i.e.`/apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}` is the watch endpoint of `Deployment` object. You may find the watch endpoint of the object you desire from the API reference of k8s-api-server. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/

Comment: I was expecting more an async kind of notification. Do not want to keep a request stream open to k8s API

Comment: It's an async kind of notification already.  k8s-api-server  creates stay-alive connection with client. Your connection won't close without you see events. https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch here you can check an example of watches, written in golang.

Comment: What i meant is that I do not have a running process that can keep this http connection open. Eventually i need to trigger lambda function whenever some changes are made to pods